# How to join results of a query to another query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
SELECT customer_trn, avg(balance) FROM 
  ( 
  SELECT depositor.customer_trn, account.account_number, account.balance FROM 
    account 
      INNER JOIN savings_account ON account.account_number = savings_account.account_number 
      INNER JOIN depositor ON depositor.account_number = account.account_number 
    UNION ALL 
  SELECT depositor.customer_trn, account.account_number, account.balance FROM 
    account 
      INNER JOIN checking_account ON account.account_number = checking_account.account_number 
      INNER JOIN depositor ON depositor.account_number = account.account_number 
  ) 
  AS subquery2 GROUP BY customer_trn ;
```

The query above produces the following result.

```
+--------------+---------------+
| customer_trn | avg(balance)  |
+--------------+---------------+
| 125-233-001  | 252500.000000 |
| 125-233-002  |   3732.500000 |
| 125-233-004  | 480002.000000 |
| 125-233-005  |  17000.000000 |
| 125-233-006  |  17000.000000 |
| 125-233-007  |   5000.000000 |
| 125-233-008  |   5000.000000 |
+--------------+---------------+
```

I am trying join that query to obtain name (from the table below) along with the initial results. Essentially, I want to link `customer_trn` (primary key) as the common column so I can make the table results more meaningful. 
It would have the customer name, customer trn and the average balance.

```
CREATE TABLE customer
   (
    customer_trn   varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    customer_name   varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    customer_street  varchar(50)  NOT NULL,
    customer_city  varchar(50)  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(customer_name)
    );
```

So it would look like:

```
+--------------+---------------+---------------+
| customer_trn | avg(balance)  |customer_name  |
+--------------+---------------+---------------+
| 125-233-001  | 252500.000000 |John           |
| 125-233-002  |   3732.500000 |Bobby          |  
| 125-233-004  | 480002.000000 |James          |
| 125-233-005  |  17000.000000 |King           |
| 125-233-006  |  17000.000000 |Raven          |
| 125-233-007  |   5000.000000 |Mark           |
| 125-233-008  |   5000.000000 |Sam            |
+--------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use join with the  customer table and subquery

```
SELECT subquery2.customer_trn, c.customer_name   ,avg(balance) FROM 
  ( 
  SELECT depositor.customer_trn, account.account_number, account.balance FROM 
    account 
      INNER JOIN savings_account ON account.account_number = savings_account.account_number 
      INNER JOIN depositor ON depositor.account_number = account.account_number 

    UNION ALL 
  SELECT depositor.customer_trn, account.account_number, account.balance FROM 
    account 
      INNER JOIN checking_account ON account.account_number = checking_account.account_number 
      INNER JOIN depositor ON depositor.account_number = account.account_number 
  ) 
  AS subquery2 join customer c on c.customer_trn =subquery2.customer_trn 

GROUP BY subquery2.customer_trn,c.customer_name ;
```

Comment: It says `Column 'customer_trn' in field list is ambiguous` when I run your solution.

Comment: @NicoleFoster answer edited i was missing table.column name i have to use that because customer table also that column

Comment: Thanks, does the job

Comment: After 6 mins it says.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have a table customer  with customer_name and id for join  customer_trn 
you could

```
SELECT t1.customer_trn, t1.cust_avg, c.username 
from (
SELECT customer_trn, avg(balance)  cust_avg
FROM 
  ( 
  SELECT depositor.customer_trn, account.account_number, account.balance 
  FROM account 
      INNER JOIN savings_account ON account.account_number = savings_account.account_number 
      INNER JOIN depositor ON depositor.account_number = account.account_number 
    UNION ALL 
   SELECT depositor.customer_trn, account.account_number, account.balance FROM 
    account 
      INNER JOIN checking_account ON account.account_number = checking_account.account_number 
      INNER JOIN depositor ON depositor.account_number = account.account_number 
  )   AS subquery2 
  GROUP BY customer_trn 

) t1 
inner join  customer ON c.id = t1.customer_trn
```